# how to compile/jump-debug using cmake/gcc within vim

Tags: c++, bash, gcc, vim

I currently use vim/byobu-tmux to multiplex between a command line (cmake/gcc) and a vim session.

*Is there a way to do the following directly within the vim session?*

1. Compile within vim (I currently use a `cmakedbg` bash alias in a command line/bash session)
2. Jump to files/location where the compile has failed

all within vim, that would save me a lot of time.

Comment: Did you try `set makeprg=cmakedbg`? Then `:make` should compile and if it fails it should automatically jump to the error. This works usually, but might need some tweaking depending on the setup.

Comment: @pfnuesel I just tweaked it a bit and got it working with cmake and parallel builds.  I will play around with it some more so I can transfer the functionality from my bash script/alias into some vim commands (things like running unit tests if the build succeeds).  Please add an answer so I can accept and give you credit: tyvm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try

```
set makeprg=cmakedbg
```

Then

```
:make
```

should compile and if it fails it should automatically jump to the error (while `:make!` would compile without jumping to the error). This works usually, but might need some tweaking depending on the setup.

If you need to `source .bashrc` before `cmakedbg` works, you can make the shell interactive by

```
:set shellcmdflag=-ic
```

However, I always had problems with that. I know it's working for some people, but when I try that, [vim](/questions/tagged/vim) is stopped by the interactive mode. I can get it back by typing `fg`, but that's not what I want.

I think the best way to do it is to set up a function in [vim](/questions/tagged/vim) and do it without `.bashrc`.